# Comparator.nullsFirst with null-safe-comparator

Tags: java-8

I want to have a null-safe comparator, but it does not work:

```
Comparator<Item> sort_high = (i1, i2)-> Double.compare(i2.getUser().getValue(), i1.getUser().getValue());

items.sort(Comparator.nullsFirst(sort_high));
```

However, I get a NPE, if item.getUser().getValue() (or item.getUser()) is null.

```
at Item.lambda$1(Item.java:270)
    at java.util.Comparators$NullComparator.compare(Comparators.java:83)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1438)
    at java.util.List.sort(List.java:478)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`nullsFirst` will take care of null `Item`s ("`i1`"), but once two valid objects are found, your `Comparator` is invoked and you need to handle internal `null` references.

In your case, you could use something like:

```
items.sort(
  Comparator.nullsFirst(
    Comparator.comparing(Item::getUser,
      Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparingDouble(User::getValue))
    )
  )
);
```

(Assuming `getValue()` returns a `double`)

But I hardly recommend such convoluted code.

Comment: yes, this works. Did not find a shorter solution..What I can do is to set property of value from Double to double..so double will never return "null".

Comment: converting to double does not work..so I stick with your solution.

Answer (score 4):

`Comparator.nullsFirst()` doesn't mean that any `NullPointerException` thrown during the `compare()` method will be caught.
It says rather that a `null` compared object with always be less than a non `null` compared object and that if both are `null`, they are considered equal.

```
 <T> Comparator<T> java.util.Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator<? super
 T> comparator)
```

> Returns a null-friendly comparator that considers null to be less than
>   non-null. When both are null, they are considered equal. If both are
>   non-null, the specified Comparator is used to determine the order. If
>   the specified comparator is null, then the returned comparator
>   considers all non-null values to be equal.

In your case :

```
Comparator<Item> sort_high = (i1, i2)-> Double.compare(i2.getUser().getValue(), i1.getUser().getValue());
```

Compared objects are not `null`, that is `i1` or `i2` but fields of them are: `i1.getUser()` or `i2.getUser()`.

You don't have a good use case for using directly `Comparator.nullsFirst()`.
As workaround, you could use it to compare the `User` field in your `compare()` implementation as soon as one of two compared objects present a `null User` field.
I think that it is a good trade off between handling yourself `null` case and readability of the code :

```
private Comparator<User> comparatorUserNullFirst = Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparingDouble(User::getValue));

Comparator<Item> sortHigh = (i1, i2) -> {

    if (i1.getUser() == null || i2.getUser() == null) {
      return comparatorUserNullFirst.compare(i1.getUser(), i2.getUser());
    }

    return Double.compare(i2.getUser().getValue(), i1.getUser().getValue());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, that is slightly more readable but does not distinguish between an item being null and an item having a user that is  null, is the following:

```
Comparator<Item> sortLow = Comparator.comparing(item -> Optional.ofNullable(item)
                .map(Item::getUser)
                .map(User::getValue)
                .orElse(null),
                 Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())                               
);
```

Comment: Debugger says: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparator<Object> to Comparator<Item>.

Comment: Stange, it works just fine when I run it. Maybe you can show me the exact code you ran ?

Comment: ... I have no idea then. At this point I am randomly guessing. You might try to add some type annotation to see if it helps eclipse: Comparator.<Item, Double>comparing

Comment: Thanks, however, I will stick the solution above. When using comparator<Object>, then debugger does not complain.

Comment: That is strange indeed. Anyway, use what seems best to you  ^^.