# Sorting list of custom object where the property on which we are sorting can be null

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to sort a List of Custom Object(lets assume **Student**) i.e. `List<Student>`
in **descencing order** of their **joiningDate**. Now it is allowed to have **joiningDate** as **null**. In such case the Student with **joiningDate** as **null** should come at **first** and then the remaining students in **descending order** of their **joiningDate**.

```
Class Student{
   Date joiningDate;
   int rollNo;
   ...
}
```

I tried the following :-

```
Comparator<Student> myComparator = Comparator.nullsFirst( 
                                       Comparator.comparing(Student::getJoiningDate, 
                                                              (s1,s2)->{ return s2.compareTo(s1);}
                                                        ));
Collections.sort(studentsList, myComparator);
```

It works when Student object is **`null`** but not when the property **joiningDate** is **`null`**.

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/27556225/9050514

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects containing null elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556104/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-containing-null-elements)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparator.nullsFirst with null-safe-comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925825/comparator-nullsfirst-with-null-safe-comparator)

Answer (score 0):

*This solution is without **streams***
Implement Comparable to your class and then the put the logic in `compareTo(Student o)` method which should be overridden.

Add Interface to your class like this:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>
```

Implement the function:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    if (o.getJoiningDate() == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    return this.getJoiningDate().compareTo(o.getJoiningDate());
}
```

-1/1 could be returned if you need to have `ASC/DESC` order.